# HTML Form won't post to PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have a form like below on my index page:

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
  <b>Your name :</b> <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <b>Your e-mail :</b> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <b>Message</b><br><textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

When I click the submit button, it posts the values on the index form still instead of navigating to send.php

```
/index.php?name=chris&email=heymega%40gmail.com&message=HELLO!
```

Notice how its still on the index page. Any ideas why this is happening?

Both files exist in the root directory.

Comment: Is the server rewriting the request? Are you sure `send.php` isn't getting hit? What happens if you use `curl` to post data to `send.php` by hand?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have some JavaScript interfering on the page.

Comment: odd, you don't have any mod_rewrites?

Comment: Don't use a `<b>` element there, by the way, use a proper `<label>` with suitable `for` attribute.

Comment: What's in `send.php`? Are you redirecting to `index.php`? Do you possibly have this wrapped in another `<form>` (invalid HTML)?

Comment: are there multiple `<form>`'s on the page? Could be because you are submitting against `index.php` and **NOT** `send.php`

Comment: Can you post your whole html with the javascript???

Comment: If method='POST', then you shouldn't be getting a query string in the URL it is posted to. @Jakub is probably on the right track.

Comment: Could you give us a url or complete html? What browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks for *not* posting a URL.

Comment: So have you made any progress on this problem at all??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok really taking a shot in the dark here since you said that it isnt nested in anyother forms and that it "**still**" sends to index.php that you need to press ctrl+F5 to refresh the possibly cached version of this page. 

If that doesn't work then post your complete html code with the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Either you already have another form tag open that you haven't closed earlier on the page, or it's not liking that you have `POST` in uppercase - I believe it should be lowercase.

Comment: that should not matter at all. the post being uppercased

Comment: I know, but it's a possible cause. The "open form from earlier" is more likely though.

Comment: Wow you guys reply fast! The form isnt nested in any parent forms but I do have some javascript to toggle a Div in which the form is contained. How does javascript affect this?

Comment: @user1221847 It could mess with it any number of ways by interfering with the event. Try disabling JavaScript on the page, and then seeing if the form still doesn't work correctly- at least then you'll know it's related to the JavaScript.

Comment: POST can be either lowercase or uppercase in any recent browser, but in some very, very, very old browsers it has to be uppercase.